# JavaFX FXML Controller

Tags: events, javafx, mouse, handler, fxml

I have a question, how to set background to this:

```
@FXML
    private Label Button;
```

using event variable:

```
@FXML
    private void ButtonClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to here? Modifying the button that was clicked based on the event handler's parameter???

Comment: Yeah, i have already known the answer: Label a = (Label)event.getSource(); a.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);

Answer (score 0):

By CSS is the easy way for your need .

create new CSS file
 a.CSS

```
.button:hover {
-fx-background-color: red ;
}

.special:hover {
-fx-background-color: blue ;
 }
```

then assign this style sheet to your FXML file in scene builder 
[image]

Comment: yeah, you have used anchor variable, i wonder how to do it through event variable

Comment: setting the background style of the container which can be :
StackPane , AnchorPane . If you done tell me

Comment: you dont understand what i want to do. I want to so do something like event.getClass().setBackground() to dont define every variable.

Comment: please make your question clear enough to be able to answer , 
You want to set the background of button or the container ?
myButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
    System.out.println("Button Action");
});

Comment: I wanted to create universal method for buttons which changes their background without need to define every single button, while ago i just found way to do this, but maybe u know better way. Label a = (Label)event.getSource();
        a.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);

Comment: Yeah got it , check the answer now :)

Comment: using your way i need to create multiple methods "myButton.setOnAct...", using my way i just need to set the same action for every button in xml

Comment: check this what i think you need to accomplish

Comment: yeah thanks, its the easiest way, i have one more question, is it possible to create pseudo classes like hover without another .css file but just in xml, i guess it is like in html so not?

Comment: yep, write your .special:hover {
-fx-background-color: blue ;
 } , 
then select style sheet then your style class which called in this case "special"

Comment: i wrote without .css file so without containing any stylesheet, just in xml file i mean something like: <Label style="-fx-border-color: black; but with hover

Comment: no there is nothing like that , at least that what I know so far.